# Updating Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have created a plugin that uses custom posts. To get these to display the permalinks need re-saving, no need to change anything, they just need re-saving.

There must be a way to do this using a hook but I can't work out how to do this. The function flush_rules looks like it might do the job but it doesn't seem to work.

Sample code here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules

Comment: are you sure your htaccess is writeable?

Comment: Yes, if I update the permalinks via the dashoboard all is OK. What I want is for people installing the plugin to have their permalinks updated automatically.

Comment: where is the code you use for calling flush_rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it.

You just have to add the flush to the custom post registration:

`register_post_type('custompostname',$args);
flush_rewrite_rules(false);`

So simple really, just took me a while to find it.